# how to create popup in angular

Tags: angular, magnific-popup

I need help

I am creating a gallery with angular and magnific popup but it does not work at all well.

When I enter the html route I need to refresh the search engine so that it works otherwise it does not work.

I do not understand what the problem is.

thanks

[image: 1]
  [image: 2]
  [image: 3]
  [image: 4]

this is my service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgustinNietoService {

  private agustinNieto: AgustinNieto [] = [

{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00001.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00002.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00003.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00004.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00005.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00006.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00007.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00008.jpg' },
{ img: 'assets/img/fotografos/agustin-nieto-web/agustin-nieto-00036.jpg' }

  ];

  constructor() {
console.log('Estamos trabajando;');
  }
  getAgustinNieto() {
    return this.agustinNieto;
  }
}

export interface AgustinNieto {
  img: string;
}
```

Este es el HTML

```
<div id="modal-magic" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="gallery" *ngFor="let agustinNieto of agustinNieto">
            <a class="view" href="{{ agustinNieto.img }}"><img class="animated fadeIn" id="img-all-hzt" src="{{ agustinNieto.img }}" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is code jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.view').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    // other options
    preloader: true,
    gallery: { enabled: true },
    removalDelay: 900,
    callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
            this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
        }
    },
});
```

});

this is a component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AgustinNietoService, AgustinNieto } from '../../../../services/agustin-nieto.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-view-agustin-nieto',
  templateUrl: './all-view-agustin-nieto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-view-agustin-nieto.component.css']
})
export class AllViewAgustinNietoComponent implements OnInit {

agustinNieto: AgustinNieto[] = [];

  constructor( private _agustinNietoService: AgustinNietoService ) {

  }

 ngOnInit() {

 this.agustinNieto = this._agustinNietoService.getAgustinNieto();

 console.log( this.agustinNieto);
 }

}
```

Comment: Please insert the code instead of the images because it is easier for other users to help you

Comment: more details will be helpful for others.

Comment: I think that help @kboul 
thanks very much

Comment: I think that help @nkuma_12
thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to have a bit more information about what "it works" means.

- Is your magnificPopup launching correctly but the image is loading slowly? The image then loads immediately once you refresh the page?
- Is your magnificPopup launching correctly but the image is not loading at all? The image then loads immediately once you refresh the page?
- Is your magnificPopup not launching at all? The magnificPopup then
  launches immediately once you refresh the page?

Comment: Thumbnail Image starts correctly but when I click open the photo in another tab and when I return magnificPopup works correctly.

It's as if you need to refresh to load jquery.
But my js file is correct because print console.log in the console.